# Javascript with ROR to toggle between div content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a feature where users can toggle between 2 div content: "followers" or "pending" with both buttons visible all the time.

Javascript is not working when i click "pending" or "followers" button.

assets/javascript/followers.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var buttons = $("#buttons").find("a");
    $("buttons").click(function() {
      $(".load-pending").click(function() {
             $("#followers").css("display", "none");
             $("#pending").css("display", "block");
      });
      $(".load-followers").click(function() {
             $("#followers").css("display", "block");
             $("#pending").css("display", "none");
      });


    });
});
```

followers.html.erb

```
<div class = "container">
  <div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="load-followers">Followers</a>
    <a href="#" class="load-pending">Pending</a>
  </div>
  <div id= "followers">
    <% @followers.each do |follower| %>
       <%= render 'user', user: follower %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
  <div id="pending" style= "display:none">
    <% @requested_friendships.each do |request| %>
       <%= render 'user', user: request %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need this...

```
 $("buttons").click(function() { });
```

When you do this, you are assigning a click event to both buttons. That click event will assign new click events to each button. (the ones you have written with the class selectors).

You want to remove that call altogether and leave the others directly under $(document).ready

Here is a working JS Fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/bhb5xqqq/1/

- I substituted your .css() calls for .show() and .hide() - this is not necessary but looks nicer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("buttons").click(function()
```

'#' missing

```
$("#buttons").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

since ".load-pending" and ".load-followers" are < a> tags, you should disable default action of link (otherwise it will jump on click to hash "#" - the very top of the page):

```
    $(".load-pending").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    ...

    $(".load-followers").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    ...
```